# Boost thread_group returns empty Matrix (openCV)

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, boost, matrix

I'm trying to use thread_group from the boost libraries to manipulate matrix objects from the openCV libraries (the program is written in C++).
However when I try to save the matrices after joining the main thread again, the matrix doesn't contain any data.
Can anyone provide an example how to manipulate matrices using boost thread_group ? (I really need multithreading, since the computation takes days otherwise)

Here is the code I'm using so far:

```
Mat myMatrix;
// Start threads
boost::thread_group threadGroup;
threadGroup.create_thread(boost::bind(&manipulateMatrixFunction,myMatrix));
threadGroup.join_all();
```

The matrix is only declared in the main thread. The initialisation with number of rows, cols and datatype takes place inside "manipulateMatrixFunction". (Maybe that is part of the problem?)

Comment: Ok, I checked it out myself :). So the matrix has to be initialised before manipulating it in a thread. Still I would rather like to initialise the matrix inside the function "manipulateMatrixFunction". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `Mat` instance by reference:

```
#include <boost/ref.hpp>

//...
threadGroup.create_thread(boost::bind(&manipulateMatrixFunction,boost::ref(myMatrix)));
//...
```

But make sure that this instance outlives the thread.